# How can I instance a model for collision-detection?

Tags: c#, 3d, xna

Just started some work in c# (using xna) where I want to check collision between two objects using their models boundingspheres. Well, rather the meshes' boundingspheres, for more detailed detection between the objects.

The trick is the objects use the same model-reference. And since they both use the reference I am unwilling to manipulate the root-bones' transform. Both objects wanting to check collision have their own matrix of course.

I've run out of ideas on how to do it, so I could use some help with it. (This is also not homework, just saying.) 
I've looked at MSDN:s example of instancing a model for rendering, but that wouldn't help with my issue (as far as I know).

Any tip is appreciated!

Comment: [Sprite collision](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1995960/1997232) ? [3d collision](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20761783/1997232)?

Comment: Oh, it's 3D collision. I'll add it to the main post if it seemed unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I remembered that the boundingspheres are structs, so therefore it would be easier to copy those compared to the model. So I use the objects matrix (containing position etc) to transform the list of B-spheres I get from the model. Therefore they are on the correct position where they would be if I moved the model.